# Insert 'X' symbol into a cell using closedxml in c#

Tags: c#, closedxml

I'm aware of the following solution for adding symbols into cells using closedxml in c#

ws.Cell(1, 1).Value = "X";
i am trying to add 'X' symbol but i am getting the symbol code.

Could you please provide 'X' symbol code to me.

Answer (score 1):

`ws.Cell(1, 1).SetValue("X");`

Comment: I am trying to set color for that "X",but  it's applying the color in background.i am using the below code.ws.Range(firstCellRow, firstCellCol, lastCellRow, lastCellCol).Style.Font.FontColor = XLColor.FromHtml(color);